# How to tag an older commit in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

We are new to Git, and I want to set a tag at the beginning of our repository.
Our production code is the same as the beginning repository, but we've made commits since then.
A tag at the beginning would allow us to "roll back" production to a known, stable state.

So how to add a tag to an arbitrary, older commit?

Comment: I came here looking for help deleting an old tag locally and on a remote and eventually found this useful, maybe it'll help somebody else too: https://gist.github.com/mobilemind/7883996

Comment: And don't forget [How to push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195859/608639) because Git won't push a tag without doing something special.

Answer (score 1968, accepted):

Example:

```
git tag -a v1.2 9fceb02 -m "Message here"
```

Where `9fceb02` is the beginning part of the commit id.

You can then push the tag using `git push origin v1.2`.

You can do `git log` to show all the commit id's in your current branch.

There is also a good chapter on [tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) in the Pro Git book.

**Warning:** This creates tags with the *current date* (and that value is what will show on a GitHub releases page, for example).  If you want the tag to be dated with the commit date, please look at [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21759466/674039).

Comment: You can also do this in the right-click menu in gitk - convenient if that's how you're finding the SHA1 anyway.

Comment: Omit the `-a` and the `-m "Message here"` parts if you don't want to add a message: `git tag v1.2 9fceb02`

Comment: You can use the full commit ID, too.

Comment: @devius What's the difference between using `-a` and `-m`. The man page seems to say `-a` is implied when `-m` is used.

Comment: @JohnStrood If you use `-a` you must pass `-m` as well, but if you only use `-m` the `-a` is implied like you said, so this response could probably omit it and it would produce the same result. In my case I wasn't interested in adding the message, so that's why I omitted both options.

Comment: **`git push --tags origin master`** would push all tags on local branch to remote.
Prefer **`git push origin <tag_name>`** to just push the created tag. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195913/452708,
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: @JohnStrood -a stands for "annotated."  An annotated tag includes the date it was tagged as well as a message.  Annotated tags are the standard tags for tagging version releases.  devius is showing how to make a lightweight tag that will not include a date or message.  As devius notes, `-am` is equivalent to `-m` and if you don't use the -m option, -a will open an editor to enter the message.

Comment: Also beyond scope of OP's question, but if you want to tag the current branch's HEAD, you can simply omit the commit number.

Answer (score 252):

#### Just the Code

```sh
# Set the HEAD to the old commit that we want to tag
git checkout 9fceb02

# temporarily set the date to the date of the HEAD commit, and add the tag
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show --format=%aD | head -1)" \
git tag -a v1.2 -m"v1.2"

# push to origin
git push origin --tags

# set HEAD back to whatever you want it to be
git checkout master
```

#### Details

The answer by @dkinzer creates tags whose date is the current date (when you ran the `git tag` command), *not* the date of the commit. The Git help for `tag` has a section *["On Backdating Tags"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_backdating_tags)* which says:

> *If you have imported some changes from another VCS and would like to add tags for major releases of your work, it is useful to be able to specify the date to embed inside of the tag object; such data in the tag object affects, for example, the ordering of tags in the gitweb interface.*
>
> *To set the date used in future tag objects, set the environment variable `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` (see the later discussion of possible values; the most common form is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM").*
>
> *For example:*
>
> ```
> $ GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2006-10-02 10:31" git tag -s v1.0.1
> ```

The page *["How to Tag in Git"](https://github.com/openmelody/melody/wiki/devbest-tagging#wiki-tagging-your-way-through-history)* shows us that we can extract the time of the HEAD commit via:

```sh
git show --format=%aD  | head -1
#=> Wed, 12 Feb 2014 12:36:47 -0700
```

We could extract the date of a specific commit via:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show 9fceb02 --format=%aD | head -1)" \
git tag -a v1.2 9fceb02 -m "v1.2"
```

However, instead of repeating the commit twice, it seems easier to just change the HEAD to that commit and use it implicitly in both commands:

```
git checkout 9fceb02 

GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show --format=%aD | head -1)" git tag -a v1.2 -m "v1.2"
```

Comment: @ColonelPanic, your wish is my command! https://github.com/lucasrangit/git-custom-commands/blob/master/git-backtag

Comment: If you use Github to manage releases and care about the date shown on your project's /tags page, setting the GIT_COMMITTER_DATE is particularly important!

Comment: @ColonelPanic I gave you an upvote for the pun, and wish I could give you a second one for the code, but a github star will have to do.

Comment: On VSCODE (windows), why I got this error? `The term 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git show --format=%aD | head -1)' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni Those commands are Linux shell commands, and will not work on Windows.

Comment: @Phrogz thanks, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54562752/11671779) solved it for windows.

Comment: This worked for me. For reassurance, is it worth adding that `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` does not need anything else doing to it afterwards? (I hestitated to follow the steps here at first, because I thought there might be a missing step to restore the environment variable afterwards.)

Answer (score 214):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
git tag v1.0.0 f4ba1fc
git push origin --tags
```

with `f4ba1fc` being the beginning of the hash of the commit you want to tag and `v1.0.0` being the version you want to tag.

Answer (score 72):

**OK**, You can simply do:

```
git tag -a <tag> <commit-hash>
```

So if you want to add **tag:** 1.0.2 to commit `e50f795`, just simply do:

```
git tag -a 1.0.2 e50f795
```

Also you **add a message** at the end, using `-m`, something like this:

```
git tag -a 1.0.2 e50f795 -m "my message"
```

After all, you need to push it to the `remote`, to do that, simply do:

```
git push origin 1.0.2
```

If you have many tags which you don't want to mention them one by one, just simply do:

```
git push origin --tags
```

to push all tags together...

Also, I created the steps in the image below, for more clarification of the steps:
[image: creating tag on a commit hash]

You can also dd the tag in **Hub** or using tools like **SourceTree**, to avoid the previous steps, I logged-in to my **Bitbucket** in this case and doing it from there:

1. Go to your branch and find the **commit** you want to add the tag to and click on it:

[image: find your commit in bitbucket]

2. In the **commit page**, on the right, find where it says `No tags` and click on the `+` icon:

[image: find where it says No tags]

3. In the tag name box, add your tag:

[image: add tag name]

4. Now you see that the tag has successfully created:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, and the answers already given all work, but there's also a new option which can be considered.

If you're using SourceTree to manage your git repositories, you can right-click on any commit and add a tag to it. With another mouseclick you can also send the tag straight to the branch on origin.

Answer (score 9):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21759466/43722) by @Phrogz is great, but doesn't work on Windows. Here's how to tag an old commit with the commit's original date using Powershell:

```powershell
git checkout 9fceb02
$env:GIT_COMMITTER_DATE = git show --format=%aD | Select -First 1
git tag v1.2
git checkout master
```

Comment: When I use Powershell (instead of git bash) to checkout the commit for tagging, it throws: `fatal: reference is not a tree`

Answer (score 7):

Building upon the answers of the others, here is a one-liner solution that sets the tag date to when it actually happened, uses annotated tag and requires no `git checkout`:

```
tag="v0.1.3" commit="8f33a878" bash -c 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show --format=%aD $commit)" git tag -a $tag -m $tag $commit'
git push --tags origin master
```

where `tag` is set to the desired tag string, and `commit` to the commit hash.

Answer (score 5):

To tag a specific commit, print commits hashes first to view what commit that you want to add tag to it

```bash
git log --oneline
```

The output would like this:

```bash
dee93fc update App.js
c691fa2 autherization to roles
559528a modify depart
6aa4ad4 edit project page
```

Select commit id that you want to add tag to it and git checkout for commit id

```bash
git checkout 6aa4ad4
```

And add tag for that commit

```bash
git tag v1.0
```

And return to your branch After make this tag

```bash
git checkout branchName
```

To view all tags

```bash
git tag
```