# Git checkout revision of local repository

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout, revision

I have a local git repository for an Xcode project. How do I checkout (from Terminal) a specific revision of the project to a different folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only have a local version? No remote repositories? Define `specific version`. A branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: @reto By 'specific revision' I mean a revision other than HEAD. Maybe these are just SVN terms? If I go to Xcode I can see the project's history of commits, so I would like to checkout somewhere in the history, not only at the latest commit.

Comment: @Zeeker This doesn't help me [How to do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) it's more about archiving/exporting, I actually want to be able to commit after checkout, so that I can make the revision to be the most recent one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone a local repo into another folder:

- [clone a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1911109/6309):

  ```
  git clone -b my-branch /path/to/local/repo /path/to/new/repo
  ```
- [clone a specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20280726/6309):

  ```
  git clone -b aTag /path/to/local/repo /path/to/new/repo
  ```

Comment: Cloning without the '-b' option works for taking the most recent version of the project. But what is the difference between these two commands? They both require a remote branch. I only have one branch, and I would like to checkout at some point in the history of commits.

Comment: @AndreiMarincas no: one requires a remote branch, the other a tag. but you can remplace 'my-branch' or aTag by any SHA1 you want, allowing you to clone at any point in the history of the rpeo.

Comment: It works but I have to tag the commits first, this also helped [Git tag older commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404172/git-tag-older-commit). So using '-b' option is a must, but one last thing: what is the difference between '-b' and '--branch'? Are they the same with 'clone'? Do they create a new branch with 'checkout'?

Comment: @AndreiMarincas yes, `-b` and `--branch` are the same. For tag, the result will be a repo checked out at the right tag, but in a detached HEAD mode.