# How to "tag" a given commit with a branch?

Tags: git

I have a project with a lot of commits and I would like to create a new branch called `old` that ends with a commit `707f3c4`, which is in the past. How would I do that?

Comment: What does "ends with a commit" mean? Do you want to create a branch based on this commit?

Comment: I'd like the branch to stop with a given commit, as opposed to the "master" branch where there are commits after this one.

Comment: @d33tah Branches don't really ‘stop’ anywhere. What are you trying to achieve? Couldn't you use tags instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag older commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404172/tag-older-commit-in-git)

Comment: Do you mean creating a tag? If so, please refer to the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this:

```
git branch old 707f3c4
```

Note that a branch is only a moveable alias for a commit, it doesn't "start" or "end" anywhere or even have any history.

Answer (score 1):

This command should do the trick:

```
git checkout -b old 707f3c4
```

Comment: This also has the side-effect of checking out the new `old` branch, meaning you'll have to `git checkout master` to get back to where you were. The `git branch` command will create a branch without affecting your working directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a tag on a certain commit, you can use

```
git tag -a old 707f3c4 -m "Create old tag"
```

Then push the tag using

```
git push --tags
```